# Select2 Transform Data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

I have data like this one.

| kode | explanation |
| --- | --- |
| 082.B.2 | Test1 |
| 083.B.3 | Test2 |

Here is my function:

```
       public function selectprogram(Request $req)
      {
        if ($req->ajax())
        {
          $search = $req->get('q');
          $page = $req->get('page');
          $resultCount = 10;
          $offset = ($page - 1) * $resultCount;
          $data = Refprogram::where('kode_program','LIKE','%'.$search .'%')
          ->orWhere('uraian','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
          ->orderby('kode_program')
          ->skip($offset)
          ->take($resultCount)
          ->get(['kode_program',DB::raw("CONCAT(kode_program,' - ', uraian) AS text")]);
           $count = Refprogram::count();
           $endCount = $offset + $resultCount;
           $morePages = $endCount < $count;
           $results = array(
                "results" => $data,
                "pagination" => array(
                  "more" => $morePages
                )
              );
          return response()->json($results);
        }
      }
```

Here is my JS Select2:

```
        $('#select2-program').select2({
            multiple:false,
            placeholder:'Please select one',
            allowClear: true,
            pagination:true,
            ajax : {
              method : 'get',
              url : '{{$breadcrumbs['select2_url_program']}}',
              data :function (params) {
                return {
                  q: params.term || '',
                  page: params.page || 1
                }
               
              },

              cache:true
            }
          });
```

My question and problem is, how can i change or transform default set id by select2 that using numeric into text. I want use  kode as a value for that, not id (numeric).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/example/api',
    processResults: function (data) {
      // Transforms the top-level key of the response object from 'items' to 'results'
      return {
        results: data.items
      };
    }
  }
});
```

https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data